# Remove text which is not in any tag

Tags: jquery, html

I have the html code look like this

```
<form id="form1">
    <img src="..." />
    <input type="text" value="Text box 1" id="txt1" />
    Sample text
    <input type="hidden" value="name" />
</form>
```

I want to remove the text `Sample text` which is not in any tag.

How to remove this text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works :

```
$('#form1')
  .contents()
  .filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3; //Node.TEXT_NODE
  }).remove();
```

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7G4bX/)

Comment: This'll remove *all* of the child text nodes. You may want to put `.first()` before `.remove()`.

Comment: In this case, I want to remove that **sample text** text only. This is working for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this ..it is working :-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var $tmp = $('#form1').children().remove();
     $('#form1').text('').append($tmp);
});
```

[see the FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RMFm7/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(function(){
    var html=$('#form1').html();
    var txt=$('#form1').text();
    html=html.replace($.trim(txt),'');
    $('#form1').html(html);
});
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4FBqj/1/)